# How can I render array members by name in an angular.js view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object in the scope that looks like this in JSON:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "members": [
        { "name": "bar", "value": 123 },
        { "name": "baz", "value": 456 },
        { "name": "qux", "value": 789 }
    ]
}
```

In my Angular views I can iterate through the `members` fairly easily:

```
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="member in members">{{member.name}} - {{member.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

However, what if I want to show specific `member` found by some arbitrary predicate? e.g. I want to show the `value` of the `member` with `name` of `"bar"`.

Imagine if Angular supported this using C#'s lambda predicate syntax, I imagine it would resemble this:

```
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
<p>Bar: {{members[ m => m.name == "bar" ].value}}</p>
```

...but Angular doesn't support this right now :) So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Use a function

One way would be to use a function to filter the set.  You could make this more *generic*, but this should give you the right idea:

[Example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3drfrR?p=preview)

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="member in data.members">{{member.name}} - {{member.value}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div>Bar: {{ filterByName(data.members, 'bar').value }}</div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
  app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
        "name": "foo",
        "members": [
            { "name": "bar", "value": 123 },
            { "name": "baz", "value": 456 },
            { "name": "qux", "value": 789 }
        ]
    };

    $scope.filterByName = function(members, value) {

       return _.find(members, function(m) { return m.name === value; });
    }
  });
```

I brought in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to help with the filter, but you could do that bit any number of ways.

### 2. Use Angular Filter

Another way, would be to use an angular `filter`:

[Example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cGg4JK?p=preview)

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="member in data.members">{{member.name}} - {{member.value}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div>Bar: {{ (data.members | filter:{name:'bar'} )[0].value }}</div>
  </body>
```

The above example uses the *out of the box* filter, but you can create [custom filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) as well.